# In Scala, how do I mixin java interfaces into Scala code

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have

```
interface ICar {...}
class Car implements ICar {...}
```

In Scala I wish to do

```
new MyScalaClass with ICar
```

But use the java implementation of ICar i.e. Car. What is the syntax for doing this?

Comment: @Kipton: What you just said is wrong, when you're talking about a `new` expression.

Comment: @Ken: You're right, I was thinking of defining a new class.

Comment: I must have missed something, what is the reason why you don't declare MyScalaClass as extending Car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use object aggregation, but encapsulating the aggregation in a trait. Suppose you have the following Java code:

```
interface ICar {
  public void brake();
}
public class Car implements ICar {
  public void brake() { System.out.println("BRAKE !!!"); }
}
```

Then you can define the following Scala trait:

```
trait HasCar { self: ICar =>
  private val car = new Car
  def brake() = car.brake()
}
```

And finally you can mix everything you need into your class:

```
 val c = new MyScalaClass extends ICar with HasCar
 c.brake // prints "BRAKE !!!"
```

Answer (score 2):

`new MyScalaClass with ICar` is the syntax for doing that, but if there are methods in `ICar` that aren't implemented in `MyScalaClass`, `MyScalaClass with ICar` is an abstract class and can't be constructed. Hence, you'll need to provide method bodies for the methods in `ICar`.

```
// ICar.java
interface ICar{
  void drive();
}

//MyScalaClass.scala
class MyScalaClass{
   def brake = ()
}

//UseIt.Scala

// error: object creation impossible, since method 
// drive in trait ICar of type => Unit is not defined
val foo = new MyScalaClass with ICar

// this works
val foo = new MyScalaClass with ICar { def drive = println("Driving") }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix two classes using `with`. Only one class is allowed, plus any number of traits or interfaces. Hence:

```
class MyScalaClass
class Car
new MyScalaClass with Car
// error: class Car needs to be a trait to be mixed in
```